# Ansible lookup values from complex structure?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, amazon-vpc

I'm working on an Ansible playbook where I use the `ec2_vpc_subnet_facts` to register facts about subnets in a VPC like:

```
- ec2_vpc_subnet_facts:
    region: "{{ ec2_region }}"
    filters:
      vpc-id: "{{ vpc.vpc.id }}"
  register: vpc_subnet_facts
```

thus getting back a structure like (removed irrelevant attributes):

```
"vpc_subnet_facts": {
    "changed": false,
    "subnets": [
        {
            ...
            "id": "subnet-0bb50753",
            ...
            "tags": {
                "Name": "mytag1"
            },
            ...
        },
        {
            ...
            "id": "subnet-0bb50754",
            ...
            "tags": {
                "Name": "mytag2"
            },
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

Later in the playbook, when creating the EC2 instances the idea is to lookup a subnet ID based on tag value for the `ec2`modules `vpc_subnet_id`attribute, i.e. having `mytag1` looking up the associated subnet ID `subnet-0bb50753`.

My current approach is to create a `tag => subnet-ID` dictionary using `set_facts` from the `ec2_vpc_subnet_facts` result but I'm interested in alternatives.

Regards, Ola

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[selectattr](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#selectattr) jinja filter is your friend here:

```
- debug: msg="{{ (vpc_subnet_facts.subnets | selectattr('tags.Name','equalto','mytag1') | first).id }}"
```

What is done here: make a subset of elements from `vpc_subnet_facts.subnets` where `tags.Name=='mytag1'`, take first element, take `id` field.

Comment: What is meant by `| first` / `take first element`? Is it *If there are multiple attributes equal to "mytag1" then take the first one* ?

Comment: In this case: if there are multiple subnets with `tags.Name=='mytag1'` take the first one. Even if you know that there will be always one and only one such element, the result of `selectattr` is of a list kind, but you want the exact item to access its `.id`.