# Searching a value in a list of dict in Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

First of all, I know it's kind of a duplicate question : I found similar topics here : 
[Searching for key in a list of dicts in Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48426663/searching-for-key-in-a-list-of-dicts-in-ansible), [Ansible lookup values from complex structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39685255/ansible-lookup-values-from-complex-structure)

I don't know if I have to ask my question directly within those topics or not, if so, I sincerely apologize.

Anyways, in Ansible, I need to extract a specific ID within an API query from a web application.
I have this code :

```
- name: API query
  uri:
    method: GET
    url: "{{ apiquery }}"
    headers:
      Content-Type: application/json
      App-Token: "{{ appToken }}"
      Session-Token: "{{ currentSessionToken.json.session_token }}"
  register: wantedState

- name: DEBUG | wantedState output
  debug:
    msg: "{{ wantedState }}"
```

The message is this :

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "accept_range": "State 1000",
        "access_control_expose_headers": "content-type, content-range, accept-range",
        "cache_control": "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate",
        "changed": false,
        "connection": "close",
        "content_length": "138",
        "content_range": "0-1/2",
        "content_type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        "cookies": {},
        "cookies_string": "",
        "date": "Thu, 24 Jan 2019 11:51:42 GMT",
        "expires": "Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT",
        "failed": false,
        "json": {
            "content-range": "0-1/2",
            "count": 2,
            "data": [
                {
                    "1": "state1",
                    "2": 12
                },
                {
                    "1": "state11",
                    "2": 10
                }
            ],
            "order": "ASC",
            "sort": 1,
            "totalcount": 2
        },
        "msg": "OK (138 bytes)",
        "pragma": "no-cache",
        "redirected": false,
        "server": "Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)",
        "status": 200,
        "url": "..."
    }
}
```

What I need is to get the proper ID associated with the stateName variable.

I followed the advice given in the two other topics and my syntax is this one:

```
- name: DEBUG | Displaying ID
  debug:
    msg: "{{ (wantedState.json.data | selectattr('1', 'equalto', stateName) | list | first).2 }}"
```

I got the following error message :

```
"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: dict object has no element 1"
```

I don't know why my query is not functioning properly to be honnest ...

Thanks in advance,

Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jinja2 converts integer-like strings to numbers under the hood.
So `'1'` and `'2'` are used to refer the first and the second elements of a list.
I don't know any way to disable this behaviour in Jinja2.

You have correct syntax in general. If your data items have keys `a` and `b` and not `1` and `2`, you'd be OK.

For your case you can use JMESPath to filter items:

```
- name: DEBUG | Displaying ID
  debug:
    msg: "{{ (wantedState.json.data | json_query('[?\"1\"==`'+stateName+'`]') | first)['2'] }}"
```

Note that:

- double quotes around `1` are escaped, because we are inside YAML quoted string `msg: "..."`
- there are JMESPath literal quotes (back quote) around stateName value
- resulting value is accessed via `['2']` (string) and not `.2` (int)

Comment: Hello Konstantin, thanks, it works like a charm ! I didn't know about the integer-like strings conversion. Sadly, I can't change the keys as the application is built like that.
Thanks again :)